# Where can I find the user documentation for my old Freenas 0.7?

Tags: documentation, freenas

Every document links seem to have been replaced with the notice (to force me) to upgrade.

I know that I am supposed to upgrade but I would like to get hands on the old FreenNAS 0.7 Khasadar user documentation (setup and installation) in any form or kind, none the less.

I am especially interested in the instructions regarding the embedded installation (setup and user guide).

Where can I get this legacy document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [FreeNAS7 repository](https://github.com/freenas/freenas7) in the [FreeNAS github](https://github.com/freenas) repository which has some of the documentation that you're looking for. Specifically there's a [docs directory](https://github.com/freenas/freenas7/tree/master/doc) which has some of the documentation.

Comment: Thank you for the link but that is more of a developer's documentation. I am looking for the information on how to _use/install/setup_ Freenas 0.7 (specifically the embedded variant.

Comment: Correct. That as all the documentation I could find. I'll keep looking but it seems as though they went out of their way to take it all off after FreeNAS was sold, and the v0.7 branch became [NAS4Free](http://www.nas4free.org/). You might want to look at the docs for that project since it's essentially the v0.7 branch.

Comment: Indeed it seems completely wiped off the net. I couldn't even find anything useful in the [web archives](http://web.archive.org/web/20110408112325/http://freenas.org/documentation/setup_and_user_guide).

Comment: @zsawyer - I haven't been able to find anything further. I think what you have here is all you're going to find.